# Javascript - Problems while converting of secondary set of emojis (UCS2) with punycode.js

Tags: javascript, unicode, punycode

When i run the punycode.ucs2.decode

("This is a message with emoji  ⚽ ⛄  )       ")

I'm obtaining numbers greater than 0xFFFF (65536) in codes. That causes me a problem because i need to convert this into a paddedHexString. So i have to pad the string to 6 digits when i am receiving that emojis.

It looks like it is happening with secondary set of emojis in the document.

http://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/1.0/emoji-data.txt

Function that breaks

```
function toPaddedHexString(num, len) {
        const str = num.toString(16).toUpperCase();
        return "0".repeat(len - str.length) + str;
 }
```

Comment: What should `punycode.ucs2.decode("")` return? `decode` returns an array of code points.

Comment: Yes, in the array i'm getting numbers greater than 65536, that causes that i get 1F60A instead of D83DDE0A that was surrogated.

Comment: But the codepoint of `` is 128525, so `decode` works properly. Surrogate pairs are used only by some encodings. How are you using the these code points?

Comment: What i need is a padded string of 4 digits each but if it is greater the second script in my edit breaks...

Comment: What is this code supposed to do though? What encoding are you trying to implement?

Comment: I think i was confused of what to do. I am trying to build a binary text field with UCS2 encoding, but provider asked me to have each letter in 4 hex digits, so the function toPaddedHexString allows me to do that, but when i receive some emojis it breaks because. Another possibility is only to pad all letters to 6 hex digits, but in a message of 100 chars it converts to an string with 600 of length, to i think is better to surrogate that characters to keep the length as short as possible

Comment: After look into it, i noticed that the problem isn't at punycode.js but at the implementation of the algorithm to convert the text...